# Angular Material - testing MatPaginator

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-material

When I am trying to test a component's method which sets a value for the `MatPaginator` from Angular Material, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'pageIndex' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

Component:

```
resetVacancySearch = () => {
    this.isVacanciesSearchMode = false;
    this.searchVacanciesValue = '';
    this.paginatorVacancies.pageIndex = 0; // reset to the first page
    this.paginatorVacancies.pageSize = 10;
    this.getVacanciesList(0, 10, 'name', 'ASC');
}
```

Test file:

```
it('should call sourcingService.getVacanciesList and reset the search value from the input field', () => {
        spyOn(sourcingService, 'getVacanciesList').and.returnValue(Observable.of());
        component.resetVacancySearch();
        expect(sourcingService.getVacanciesList).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0, 10, 'name', 'ASC');
        expect(component.searchVacanciesValue).toEqual('');
 });
```

The application works fine, but I cannot get an instance of the MatPaginator into the test file. Can someone please advise how can I mock MatPaginator into the test? Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Comment: Can u provide the solution for this question?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to access paginator defined in the component in the test class.

In the component.ts, I have added this line to access paginator

`@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;`

component.html

```
<div>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" (page)="onPageChange($event)">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

In component.spec.ts,

```
beforeEach(async(() => {TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [DiscoverAddTargetDialogComponent],
  imports: [NoopAnimationsModule,MatTableModule, MatSortModule, MatPaginatorModule],
  providers: []
})
  .compileComponents();}));
```

And I accessed the paginator as follows:

`console.log("length :" + component.paginator.length);`

Answer (score 1):

Just Add

```
MatPaginatorModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule
```

in the import[] array.